# How to reference a named call from the looking up other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a named cell in my "Menu" tab called "OrangeJuice.Cost" which references "Menu!$D$2". On a new tab I have the String "OrangeJuice" in cell A1. I want to use this cell to construct the named cell above. I have the formula in this tab as =A1&".Cost". This just writes the string "OranceJuice.Cost" in the cell, without actually putting the cell value "Menu!$D$2". I guess I need to wrap it up in an indirect or lookup but whatever I try fails with #Name? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirect is the way to go:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & ".Cost")
```